# Add attributes to polygons that are adjacent to a polygon from a different layer?

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile with polygons which represent a raster which represents all countries on Earth (~70,000 cells) and one shapefile layer from NaturalEarthData which represents the worlds oceans.

How can I add an attribute to each raster cell that is adjacent to the outer border of my open shapefile or, in other words, how can I add a specific attribute to those polygons that entails the coastline?

Answer (score 1):

"Join attributes by location" and set the accuracy to about 1 km, or 0.1°.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I don't want to join them however. I just want to have an additional column in the attribute table that states that they are located next to each other.

Comment: Acually, this may work. However, running a test with only about 300 cells takes quite long (still running). Considering, that I will have 70,000 cells in my final model this may not be a suitable solution. Any other suggestions?

Comment: v.distance is the only thing that springs to my mind right now, sorry.

Comment: same as above solution that may process quicker.. spatial query, select where touches (buffer 1km in advance if needed), open attribute table, open field calculator, update the additional column on those records select.